# Reading and writing java.util.Date from Parcelable class

Tags: java, android

I'm working with Parcelable class. How can I read and write `java.util.Date` object to and from this class?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use [writeSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeSerializable%28java.io.Serializable%29) where Date is Serializable. (***But not a good idea. See below for another better way***)

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
   // Write object
   out.writeSerializable(date_object);

}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
   // Read object
    date_object = (java.util.Date) in.readSerializable();

}
```

---

> But Serializing operations consume much performance. How can overcome
>   this?

*So better use is to convert date into Long while writing, and read Long and pass to Date constructor to get Date. See below code*

```
   @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
       // Write long value of Date
       out.writeLong(date_object.getTime());

    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
       // Read Long value and convert to date
        date_object = new Date(in.readLong());

    }
```

Comment: But Serializing operations consume much performance. How can overcome this?

Comment: You really should do it using longs as Serializable is not good for performance, which is noticeable on older devices. You may also want to look at Joda as it contains lots of useful tools and has a DateTime object that I often find more useful.

Comment: Now is ok. I prefer to use long instead of serializing.

Comment: Remember take care of null dates

Comment: How to take care of null?

Comment: @PankajKumar what if there's actually a `Long` field in the class won't the parcel read it instead of the date becase I have such scenario.

Comment: @JockyDoe It will not. Sequence of fields while parcelling and un-parcelling matters. So check if you are using same order for both fields.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same but for LocalDate/LocalTime objects? the above method does not work for these types

Answer (score 19):

In **Kotlin** we may create extension for Parcel - the simplest solution.

```
fun Parcel.writeDate(date: Date?) {
    writeLong(date?.time ?: -1)
}

fun Parcel.readDate(): Date? {
    val long = readLong()
    return if (long != -1L) Date(long) else null
}
```

And use it

```
parcel.writeDate(date)
parcel.readDate()
```

Answer (score 15):

Use **date.getTime()** for get Long format:

```
public class MiClass implements Parcelable {
    Date date;

    public MiClass(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(date != null ? date.getTime() : -1);
    }

    protected MiClass(Parcel in) {
        long tmpDate = in.readLong();
        this.date = tmpDate == -1 ? null : new Date(tmpDate);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MiClass> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MiClass>() {
        public MiClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MiClass(source);
        }

        public MiClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MiClass[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but will not work properly for dates before 1/1/1970. -1L is actually a valid value to represent one millisecond before 1/1/1970. So I would rather use a value like Long.MIN_VALUE instead for better safety.

Answer (score 2):

### Try this (Kotlin):

```
data class DateParcel(val date: Date?):Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(parcel.readValue(Date::class.java.classLoader) as? Date
)

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeValue(date)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<DateParcel> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): DateParcel {
        return DateParcel(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<DateParcel?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date` class implements `Serializable`...

so you can write

```
parcel.writeSerializable(java.util.Date)
```

and you can read like

```
java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date)parcel.readSerializable();
```

Comment: While this will work I suggest users of SO takea look at the answer using longs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in this way::

for write::

```
yourParse.writeSerializable(YourGivenDate)
```

for read::

```
Date myDate = yourParse.readSerializable();
```